# How to use Custom style component for tags background color in ng2-tag-input?

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-directives, angular2-custom-component

How can I add background color to tags in ng2-tag-input plugin,I searched it ,they said that we need to use custom component for styles,I added but getting trigger is not found,i am using this https://github.com/Gbuomprisco/ng2-tag-input website.can any one help me?

video.component.ts file

```
import { Component, forwardRef } from '@angular/core';
import { TagInputComponent } from 'ng2-tag-input';
import { NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
     selector: 'custom-tag-input', 
    providers: [{
        provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
        useExisting: forwardRef(() => videoComponent ),
        multi: true
    }],
    template:`<tag-input [ngModel]="['Typescript', 'Angular 2']"></tag-input>`,
    styleUrls: [],
     animations: [
        trigger('flyInOut', [
            state('in', style({transform: 'translateX(0)'})),
            transition(':enter', [
                animate(200, keyframes([
                    style({opacity: 0, offset: 0}),
                    style({opacity: 0.5, offset: 0.3}),
                    style({opacity: 1, offset: 1.0})
                ]))
            ]),
            transition(':leave', [
                animate(150, keyframes([
                    style({opacity: 1, transform: 'translateX(0)', offset: 0}),
                    style({opacity: 1, transform: 'translateX(-15px)', offset: 0.7}),
                    style({opacity: 0, transform: 'translateX(100%)', offset: 1.0})
                ]))
            ])
        ])
    ]

})
export class videoComponent extends TagInputComponent{

     constructor(){ }

      public options = {
         readonly: undefined,
        placeholder: 'Add a tag'
    };

    public onAdd(item) {
        console.log(item + ' added');
    }

    public onRemove(item) {
        console.log(item + ' removed');
    }

    public onSelect(item) {
        console.log(item + ' selected');
    }

    public onFocus(item) {
        console.log('input focused: current value is ' + item);
    }

    public onBlur(item) {
        console.log('input blurred: current value is ' + item);
    }

    public transform(item: string): string {
        return `@${item}`;
    }

    private startsWithAt(control: FormControl) {
        if (control.value.charAt(0) !== '@') {
            return {
                'startsWithAt@': true
            };
        }
        return null;
    }
    private endsWith$(control: FormControl) {
        if (control.value.charAt(control.value.length - 1) !== '$') {
            return {
                'endsWith$': true
            };
        }
        return null;
    }
    public validators = [this.startsWithAt, this.endsWith$];
    public errorMessages = {
        'startsWithAt@': 'Your items need to start with "@"',
        'endsWith$': 'Your items need to end with "$"'
    };


}
```

app.module.ts file

```
import { TagInputModule } from 'ng2-tag-input';
import { videoComponent } from './videos/video.component'; 


@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule,

        TagInputModule, 
    ],
    declarations: [ Home, videoComponent ], // we need this here
    bootstrap: [ Home ], // this is just an example
    entryComponents: [ Home ] // this is just an example
})
export class AppModule {}
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to overwrite `tag-input` component's style by using parent component's styling. You need to use `/deep/` keyword which will tell Angular to make children inherit specified part of CSS. Sometimes you may need to use `!important` keyword to make sure that values are going to be overwritten.

You need to find corresponding css classes in component whose styling you want to modify.

Example:

```
/deep/ .example-style-which-can-be-used-by-children {
    background-color: red !important;
}
```

Look into scss of tag-input [here](https://github.com/Gbuomprisco/ng2-tag-input/blob/master/modules/components/tag/_tag.style.scss) and create corresponding classes in parent's style.